# Create a carousel with crossfading images at each slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to create a carousel that contains 2 images per slide. The carousel will start automatically and loop between slides. At each slide, the first image will crossfade to the second image. After both slides are completed the process with loop again.

```
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-slide" alt="SlideA">
      <img class="image" src="..." alt="image1">
      <img class="image" src="..." alt="image2">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-slide" alt="SlideB">
      <img class="image" src="..." alt="image3">
      <img class="image" src="..." alt="image4">
    </div>
  </div>

SlideA
show image1
fade to image2
move to SlideB

SlideB
show image3
fade to image4
Loop back to SlideA
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be 4 slides with 2 different transitions?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Slick Slider, it includes all the options to do what you described and more. It’s also very light weight.